# Appearance Proxy in Swift (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

Has anyone tried using the appearance proxy in swift yet?

This syntax doesn't work, has anyone figured out how to set title text attributes on controls like segmentedControl or UITabBar? I think I am close

```
segmentedControl.titleTextAttributesForState(UIControlState.Normal) = 
NSDictionary(objects: [UIFont(name: fontFamilyRegular, size: 16.0)], 
forKeys: [NSFontAttributeName])
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should do it:

```
segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes([
    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 16.0)!,
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blueColor()
    ], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Comment: How would you set multiple attributes using this syntax?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you unwrap the the font (!)

```
let font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size:15.0)!
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:font,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.redColor()], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Comment: Hi there, I just installed XCode 6.3.1 and iPhone 4s iOS 8.3 and it worked fine. Maybe it was the custom color? I just changed to red in the code so people can copy & past now. Please let me know if it don't work for you yet.

Answer (score 1):

For XCode 6.1, try this:

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(NSDictionary(object: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 16.0)!, forKey: NSFontAttributeName), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```